# Prove this function is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$fin$ is a collection of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. We define $f: \mathbb{N} \to fin$ recursive: $f(1) = \emptyset$ and if  $n \geq 0$ and $1 \leq k \leq 2^n$ then $f(2^n+k)=f(k) \cup \{n+1\}$

Idea for injection: if $f(x)=f(y)$, then the highest number in the image is per definition $n+1$, and thus we get $f(2^n+x')=f(2^n+y')$, from which follows $f(x')=f(y')$. Now we apply the same logic, until we lowered it to $f(1)=g(1)= \emptyset$.

Comment: Is it not the collection of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ be finite, and define $\phi(A) = \sum_{i \in A} 2^{i-1} +1$, where the summation is taken to be $0$ if $A$ is empty. If we let $\mathbb{N}^* = \{ A \subset \mathbb{N} | |A| < \infty \}$, it is straightforward by using the binary expansion of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to verify that $\phi: \mathbb{N}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ is bijective.

I need a small technical result first.
Let $\underline{n} = \begin{cases} \emptyset, & n=0 \\ \{1,...,n\}, & n>0 \end{cases}$.

Suppose $1 \le k \le 2^n$, then I claim $f(k) \subset \underline{n}$. The claim is true for $n=0$. Suppose the claim is true for all $k$ satisfying $1 \le k \le 2^n$. Then we have $f(2^n+k ) = f(k) \cup \{n+1\}$, for all $k$ satisfying $1 \le k \le 2^n$. By presumption we have $f(k) \subset \underline{n}$, hence we have $f(2^n+k ) \subset \underline{n} \cup \{n+1\} = \underline{n+1}$, hence the statement is true for $1 \le k \le 2^{n+1}$. This also shows that $f(k)$ and $\{n+1\}$ are disjoint for $1 \le k \le 2^n$.

Now I claim that $\phi(f(k)) = k$ for all $k \ge 1$. This is true if $k=1$, since $f(1) = \emptyset$.

Now suppose the claim is true for $k$ such that $1 \le k \le 2^{n}$.

Note that if $A,B \subset\mathbb{N}^*$ are disjoint, then $\phi(A \cup B ) = \phi(A) + \phi(B) -1$. Now suppose $k$ satisfies such that $1 \le k \le 2^n$, then we have $\phi(f(2^n+k)) = \phi(f(k) \cup \{ n+1 \}) = k + 2^n +1 -1 = 2^n+k$, hence we have $\phi(f(i)) = i$ for $2^n+1 \le k \le 2^{n+1}$, hence the claim is true for $1 \le k \le 2^{n+1}$.

Since $\phi \circ f$ is the identify on $\mathbb{N}$, it follows that $f$ is bijective.

In particular, if $f(k_1)=f(k_2)$, then applying $\phi$ to both sides shows $k_1 = k_2$. Now suppose $A \in \mathbb{N}^*$, then let $y=\phi(A)$. Then we have $\phi(f(y)) = \phi(f(\phi(A)) = \phi(A)$, and since $\phi$ is injective, we conclude that $f(y) = A$.

**Addendum**: To show why $\phi$ is bijective.

It is slightly more convenient to work with $\eta: \mathbb{N}^* \to \mathbb{N}_0$, where $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, and $\eta(A) = \phi(A)-1 = \sum_{i \in A} 2^{i-1}$ (the sum being $0$ if $A$ is empty). It should be clear that $\phi$ is a bijection **iff** $\eta$ is a bijection.

Choose $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, and let $n = \sum_{i \in I} 2^i$ be its binary expansion (note $I$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}_0$). Then if we let $A = I+\{1\}$ (that is, add $1$ to each element of $I$), we have $\eta(A) = n$. Hence $\eta$ is surjective.

Now suppose $\eta(A) = \eta(B)$, where $A,B \subset \mathbb{N}^*$. If $\eta(A) = 0$, then we must have $A = \emptyset$, and similarly $B= \emptyset$. So we can suppose that $\eta(A) >0$. Let $s_A = \max A$ and similarly for $s_B$. Suppose without loss of generality that $s_A \ge s_B$. Since $1+2+...+ 2^n < 2^{n+1}$, we see that we must have $s_A = s_B$, and hence $\eta(A\setminus \{s_A \}) = \eta(B\setminus \{s_B \}) $. Repeating the process shows that $A=B$, hence $\eta$ is injective.

Comment: "it is straightforward by using the binary expansion of n∈N to verify that ϕ:N∗→N is bijective." I'm having trouble with this :(

Comment: @RomanThommassen: I added a note above that hopefully explains the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need $2^{n-1} \le k \lt 2^n$, otherwise $k$ is not well specified.  This is only a bijection if $fin$ is the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.  Your injection idea is fine.  Now for surjection you need to show that every set in $fin$ is the image of some $n$.  Given a finite subset $I$, think about $\sum_{i \in I} 2^{i-1}$.  Here is where the bijection fails if you don't have all the subsets.

Comment: $f(2)=f(2^0+1)=f(1) \cup \{0+1\}=\{1\}$?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the surjection, can you elaborate?

Comment: Essentially, to get $f(n)$ you express $n-1$ in binary.  If the bit representing $2^i$ is a $1$ in the binary expansion, $i+1$ is in $f(n)$.  So  for $f(2)=\{1\}, f(8)=\{1,2,3\}, f(13)=\{3,4\}$  I was off by one in the exponenet